# Assign new value to std::function while calling

Tags: c++, lambda

```
int i = 9;
struct_variable.f = [i](T struct_variable&) {
   do_something_with_capture_variable(i);
   ...
   struct_variable.f = another_compatible_std_function;
   //do something else, but never use captured variable after here
   ...
};

struct_variable.f(struct_variable);
```

The lambda function is saved as member `struct_variable.f`(which is also typed `std::function`), and in the callback, `struct_variable.f` is replaced by `another_compatible_std_function` after finish using captured variable.

Is this practice guaranteed to be safe?

Comment: I want to say yes as long as you're careful, because the situation is analogous to `delete`-ing an object during execution of one of its member functions.  But this is hard to prove from the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

Code portion of the lambda is compiled into machine code and during assignment only pointer-to-function that point to that code is assigned. So as long as you no longer use captured variables it should be safe to re-assign the variable holding the lambda because no running code will be altered.